# Ensure a set of deferred.then callbacks completes

Tags: javascript, promise, dojo, deferred

I am using `Dojo 1.10` by the way which came with `Deferred` and `Promise` API. So the scenario is as below:

```
 var deferred_1 = new Deferred();
 deferred_1 .then(function(value){
  // do something
  return something;
 })

 var deferred_2 = new Deferred();
 deferred_2.then(function(value){
  // do something
  return something;
 })

var completeFunc = function(value){
    console.log("done");
}

//run completeFunc after completion of both deferred_1.then and 
deferred_2.then
```

How do I ensure the completion of both deferred objects callback functions in `deferred_1.then` and `deferred_2.then` are completed before running another function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` to create a Promise that resolves only after all promises you pass into it are resolved. Note that you have to save a reference to the new promises:

```
const deferred_1 = new Deferred();
const d1 = deferred_1.then(function(value) {
  // do something
  return something;
});
const deferred_2 = new Deferred();
const d2 = deferred_2.then(function(value) {
  // do something
  return something;
})
const completeFunc = function(value) {
  console.log("done");
}
Promise.all([d1, d2]).then(completeFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dojo/promise/all function.
Example from [documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise/all.html):

```
require(["dojo/promise/all"], function(all){

  all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(results){
    // results will be an Array
  });

  // -- or --

  all({
    promise1: promise1,
    promise2: promise2
  }).then(function(results){
    // results will be an Object using the keys "promise1" and "promise2"
  });

});
```