# Ensure a Callback is Complete in Mongo Node Driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am a bit new to JavaScript web dev, and so am still getting my head around the flow of asynchronous functions, which can be a bit unexpected to the uninitiated. In my particular use case, I want execute a routine on the list of available databases before moving into the main code. Specifically, in order to ensure that a test environment is always properly initialized, I am dropping a database if it already exists, and then building it from configuration files.

The basic flow I have looks like this:

```
let dbAdmin = client.db("admin").admin();
dbAdmin.listDatabases(function(err, dbs){/*Loop through DBs and drop relevant one if present.*/});
return await buildRelevantDB();
```

By peppering some `console.log()` items throughout, I have determined that the `listDatabases()` call basically puts the callback into a queue of sorts. I actually enter `buildRelevantDB()` *before* entering the callback passed to listDatabases. In this particular example, it seems to work anyway, I think because the call that reads the configuration file is also asynchronous and so puts items into the same queue but later, but I find this to be brittle and sloppy. There must be some way to ensure that the `listDatabases` portion resolves before moving forward.

The closest solution I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911357/ensure-a-set-of-deferred-then-callbacks-completes), but I still don't know how to get the callback I pass to listDatabases to be like a `then` as in that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing callbacks and promises is a bit more advanced technique, so if you are new to javascript try to avoid it. In fact, try to avoid it even if you already learned everything and became a js ninja.

Dcumentation for [listDatabases](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/Admin.html#listDatabases) says it is async, so you can just await it without messing up with callbacks:

```
const dbs = await dbAdmin.listDatabases();
/*Loop through DBs and drop relevant one if present.*/
```

The next thing, there is no need to `await` before `return`. If you can `await` within a function, it is `async` and returns a promise anyway, so just return the promise from buildRelevantDB:

```
return buildRelevantDB();
```

Finally, you can [drop database](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/Db.html#dropDatabase) directly. No need to iterate over all databases to pick one you want to drop:

```
await client.db(<db name to drop>).dropDatabase();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm fine with JS when I use it like a regular language, but these async libs are killing me. So it is not an error to drop a db that does not exist? Also, I am doing 'return await func()' because I was returning the value and not the promise, but maybe this is still too new to me.

Comment: Yes, it's okay to drop a db that doesn't exists. Wrap it in try-catch if in doubts. It's a good thing to do even if you have no doubts - it's a remote db after all. No, you you don't return value, you return a Promise. Once you declared a function `async` it returns nothing but a promise.  Async/await is just a syntax sugar, it's all promises underneath.