# Best Way to Build a Collection in Node Mongo Driver from a Directory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I asked a [similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597158/ensure-a-callback-is-complete-in-mongo-node-driver) to this, but the solution was very easy and did not really address my fundamental problem of not understanding flow control in asynchronous JavaScript. The short version of what I am trying to do is build a MongoDB collection from a directory of JSON files. I had it working, but I modified something and now the flow is such that the program runs to completion, and therefore closes the connection before the asynchronous `insertOne()` calls are executed. When the `insertOne()` calls are finally executed, the data is not input and I get warnings about an unhandled exception from using a closed connection.

I am new to this, so if what I am doing is not best practice (it isn't), please let me know and I am happy to change things to get it to be reliable. The relevant code basically looks like this:

```
fs.readDirSync(dataDir).forEach(async function(file){

    //logic to build data object from JSON file

    console.log('Inserting object ' + obj['ID']);
    let result = await connection.insertOne(obj);
    console.log('Object ' + result.insertedId + ' inserted.');

})
```

The above is wrapped in an `async` function that I `await` for. By placing a `console.log()` message at the end of program flow, followed by a `while(true);`, I have verified that all the "'Inserting object ' + obj[ID]" messages are printed, but not the following "'Object ' + result.insertedId + ' inserted'" messages when flow reaches the end of the program. If I remove the `while(true);` I get all the error messages, because I am no longer blocking and obviously by that point the client is closed. In no case is the database actually built.

I understand that there are always learning curves, but it is really frustrating to not be able to do something as simple as flow control. I am just trying to do something as simple as "loop through each file, perform function on each file, close, and exit", which is remedial programming. So, what is the best way to mark a point that flow control will *not pass* until all attempts to insert data into the Collection are complete (either successfully or unsuccessfully, because ideally I can use a flag to mark if there were any errors)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better answer than my original, so I am going to post it for anyone else who needs this in the future, as there does not seem to be too much out there. I will leave my original hack up too, as it is an interesting experiment to run for anyone curious about the asynchronous queue. I will also note for everyone that there is a pretty obvious way to [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), but it seems that this would put all files into memory at once which is what I am trying to avoid, so I am not going to write up that solution too.

This method uses the [Node fs Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api), specifically the [fsPromises readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options) method. I'll show the results running three test files I made in the same directory that have `console.log()` messages peppered throughout to help understand program flow.

This first file (`without-fs-prom.js`) uses the ordinary read method and demonstrates the problem. As you can see, the asynchronous functions (the `doFile()` calls) do not terminate until the end. This means anything you wanted to run only *after* all the files are processed would be run before processing finished.

```
/*
** This version loops through the files and calls an asynchronous
** function with the tradidional fs API (not the Promises API).
*/

const fs = require('fs');

async function doFile(file){
  console.log(`Doing ${file}`);
  return true;
}

async function loopFiles(){

  console.log('Enter loopFiles(), about to loop through the files.');

  fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(async function(file){
    console.log(`About to do file ${file}`);
    ret = await doFile(file);
    console.log(`Did file ${file}, returned ${ret}`);
    return ret;
  });

  console.log('Done looping through the files, returning from loopFiles()');

}

console.log('Calling loopFiles()');
loopFiles();
console.log('Returned from loopFiles()');

/* Result of run:

> require('./without-fs-prom')
Calling loopFiles()
Enter loopFiles(), about to loop through the files.
About to do file with-fs-prom1.js
Doing with-fs-prom1.js
About to do file with-fs-prom2.js
Doing with-fs-prom2.js
About to do file without-fs-prom.js
Doing without-fs-prom.js
Done looping through the files, returning from loopFiles()
Returned from loopFiles()
{}
> Did file with-fs-prom1.js, returned true
Did file with-fs-prom2.js, returned true
Did file without-fs-prom.js, returned true

*/
```

The problem can be partially fixed using the fsPromises API as in `with-fs-prom1.js` follows:

```
/*
** This version loops through the files and calls an asynchronous
** function with the fs/promises API and assures all files are processed
** before termination of the loop.
*/

const fs = require('fs');

async function doFile(file){
  console.log(`Doing ${file}`);
  return true;
}

async function loopFiles(){

  console.log('Enter loopFiles(), read the dir');

  const files = await fs.promises.readdir(__dirname);

  console.log('About to loop through the files.');

  for(const file of files){
    console.log(`About to do file ${file}`);
    ret = await doFile(file);
    console.log(`Did file ${file}, returned ${ret}`);
  }

  console.log('Done looping through the files, returning from loopFiles()');

}

console.log('Calling loopFiles()');
loopFiles();
console.log('Returned from loopFiles()');

/* Result of run:

> require('./with-fs-prom1')
Calling loopFiles()
Enter loopFiles(), read the dir
Returned from loopFiles()
{}
> About to loop through the files.
About to do file with-fs-prom1.js
Doing with-fs-prom1.js
Did file with-fs-prom1.js, returned true
About to do file with-fs-prom2.js
Doing with-fs-prom2.js
Did file with-fs-prom2.js, returned true
About to do file without-fs-prom.js
Doing without-fs-prom.js
Did file without-fs-prom.js, returned true
Done looping through the files, returning from loopFiles()

*/
```

In this case, code after the file iteration loop *within the asynchronous function itself* runs after all files have been processed. You can have code in *any* function context with the following construction (file `with-fs-prom2.js`):

```
/*
** This version loops through the files and calls an asynchronous
** function with the fs/promises API and assures all files are processed
** before termination of the loop. It also demonstrates how that can be
** done from another asynchrounous call.
*/

const fs = require('fs');

async function doFile(file){
  console.log(`Doing ${file}`);
  return true;
}

async function loopFiles(){

  console.log('Enter loopFiles(), read the dir');

  const files = await fs.promises.readdir(__dirname);

  console.log('About to loop through the files.');

  for(const file of files){
    console.log(`About to do file ${file}`);
    ret = await doFile(file);
    console.log(`Did file ${file}, returned ${ret}`);
  }

  console.log('Done looping through the files, return from LoopFiles()');

  return;

}

async function run(){
  console.log('Enter run(), calling loopFiles()');
  await loopFiles();
  console.log('Returned from loopFiles(), return from run()');
  return;
}

console.log('Calling run()');
run();
console.log('Returned from run()');

/* Result of run:

> require('./with-fs-prom2')
Calling run()
Enter run(), calling loopFiles()
Enter loopFiles(), read the dir
Returned from run()
{}
> About to loop through the files.
About to do file with-fs-prom1.js
Doing with-fs-prom1.js
Did file with-fs-prom1.js, returned true
About to do file with-fs-prom2.js
Doing with-fs-prom2.js
Did file with-fs-prom2.js, returned true
About to do file without-fs-prom.js
Doing without-fs-prom.js
Did file without-fs-prom.js, returned true
Done looping through the files, return from LoopFiles()
Returned from loopFiles(), return from run()

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

This was my first tentative answer. It is a hack of a solution at best. I am leaving it up because it is an interesting experiment for people who want to peer into the asynchronous queue, and there may be some real use case for this somewhere too. I think my newly posted answer is superior in all reasonable cases, though.

**Original Answer**

I found a bit of an answer. It is a hack, but further searching on the net and the lack of responses indicate that there may be no real good way to reliably control flow with asynchronous code and callbacks. Basically, the modification is along the lines of:

```
fs.readDirSync(dataDir).forEach(async function(file){

    jobsOutstanding++;

    //logic to build data object from JSON file

    console.log('Inserting object ' + obj['ID']);
    let result = await connection.insertOne(obj);
    console.log('Object ' + result.insertedId + ' inserted.');

    jobsOutstanding--;

})
```

Where `jobsOutstanding` is a top level variable to the module with an accessor, `numJobsOutstanding()`.

I now wrap the close like this (with some logging to watch how the flow works):

```
async function closeClient(client){
    console.log("Enter closeClient()");
    if(!client || !client.topology || !client.topology.isConnected()){
        console.log("Already closed.");
    }
    else if(dataObject.numJobsOutstanding() == 0){
        await client.close();
        console.log("Closed.");
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(function(){ closeClient(client);}, 100);
    }
}
```

I got this one to run correctly, and the logging is interesting to visualize the asynchronous queue. I am not going to accept this answer yet to see if anyone out there knows something better.